# expressjs - using middleware function

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to know how I can move the following code into a separate function (in the same file) and call upon it when either I call the POST or PUT routes to add or update documents.

I'm using https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-validator

The following is currently in my POST route but when I'm updating a record the title will still need to be validated.

```
app.post('/docs', auth, function (req, res) {
  req.checkBody('title', 'Title is required').notEmpty();
  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if(errors){
    res.json(400, { errors: errors });
    return;
  }

  //go ahead and save the document

});
```

I've tried making my own function but I'm not sure where to put the `var errors = req.validationErrors();` or whether it's bad practice to return 400 errors from a separate function.

Any help/code much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of the [middleware function](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use) is almost identical to the code you are using right now, only with two notable differences:

- The function ensures that the `req.method` is either POST or PUT.
- The `next()` function is called when validation passes. This will trigger the next middleware function in the chain, or the route handler.

```
app.use('/docs', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.method == 'POST' || req.method == 'PUT') {
    req.checkBody('title', 'Title is required').notEmpty();
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
      res.json(400, { errors: errors });
      return;
    }
  }
  next();
});

app.post('/docs', auth, function (req, res) {
  // go ahead and save the document
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this - so if I understand it right the POST and PUT routes for `/docs` will first be subjected to the `app.use` beforehand right?

Comment: @tommyd456:  Correct!